# GroupBy to identify items with different scores and the number of times they are assigned different scores

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have the following Model classes: `Assessment` and `AssessmentItem`. Each assessment is submitted by a unique user for a specific `Submission`, associated with a `Rubric`. Each `Assessment` may have many `AssessmentItems`, which is composed of a score assigned by the user and the id of the associated rubric item (`RubricItemId`). Basically, many users can assess a submission using multiple `RubricItemId` values (as criteria).

```
public class Assessment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubmissionId")]
    public Submission Submission { get; set; }
    public int SubmissionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RubricId")]
    public Rubric Rubric { get; set; }
    public int RubricId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EvaluatorId")]
    public ApplicationUser Evaluator { get; set; }
    public string EvaluatorId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<AssessmentItem> AssessmentItems { get; set; }
}

public class AssessmentItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CurrentScore { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RubricItemId")]
    public RubricItem RubricItem { get; set; }
    public int RubricItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssessmentId")]
    public Assessment Assessment { get; set; }
    public int AssessmentId { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to find the `RubricItemId` values with different scores per each submission, along with the number of times they were assigned different scores across all submissions. For example, RubricItem #1 was scored differently by users in 10 submissions. However, I do not know where to start. I have the following code to do this without taking into account the submission.

```
var a = _context.AssessmentItems.GroupBy(ai => ai.AssessmentId)
                .Where(da => da.Select(d => d.CurrentScore)
                               .Distinct()
                               .Count() == 1
                       );
```

This code neither computers the count when RubricItemId is assigned different scores. I wonder how I can move forward from here. Should I use `GroupBy`. If I want to do this per Submission, I believe there has to be another `GroupBy` using `SubmissionId`, right? Any tips and suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could provide some C# format sample data, I could test. This is my attempt - since I am not building against EF you may need an `AsEnumerable` at some point, which could pull the whole database over.

```
var ans = _context.Assessments
            .GroupBy(a => a.SubmissionId)
            .SelectMany(a_sg => a_sg.SelectMany(a => a.AssessmentItems)
                                    .GroupBy(ai => new { ai.RubricItemId, ai.CurrentScore})
                                    .Where(ai_ricsg => ai_ricsg.Count() > 1)
                                    .Select(ai_ricsg => new { ai_ricsg.Key.RubricItemId, DifferentScoreCountPerSubmission = ai_ricsg.Count() })
            )
            .GroupBy(ric => ric.RubricItemId)
            .Select(ric_rig => new { RubricItemId = ric_rig.Key, DifferentScoreCount = ric_rig.Sum(ric => ric.DifferentScoreCountPerSubmission) });
```

Answer (score 2):

NetMage beat me to it and probably will be closer to what you end up needing. I can confirm his answer should work without needing to materialize the entities:

Since you are wanting details at a submission level, the start of the query should likely be at the Assessment level.

At a high level you will probably be looking to group on the Submission then utilizing `SelectMany` with a further group-by to drill down to the items you want to count.

```
var query = _context.Assessments.GroupBy(x => x.SumbissionId)
   .SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(g => g.AssessmentItems
      .Select(ai => new { SubmissionId = g.Key, ai.CurrentScore, ai.RubricItemId})
      .GroupBy(ai => ai);
```

This would just be a start, which will get you a structure that can count the distinct combinations of Submission, Score, and RubricItem. I've verified this /w EF6 against a database, so extending out like what NetMage has outlined should be possible without materializing it, or at worst, materializing it as something like the above.

The key thing in this case would be to deal with FKs and particular fields wherever possible rather than pulling back entire entities in the Linq queries as a query like this will probably have a pretty big footprint on DB row touches.